# Conditionally Merging list of lists with rows of a text file

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension

Consider these two data structures:

```
var_a = [['apple','fruit','1'],['banana', 'fruit', '2'],['orange', 'fruit', '3']]
```

text file contents:

```
'1', '20,000', 'USA'
'2', '45,000', 'Russia'
'3', '56,000', 'China'
```

I want to use a list comprehension that will give me an output as follows:

```
'Apple', '1', '20,000', 'USA'
'Banana', '2', '45,000', 'Russia'
'Orange', '3', '56,000', 'China'
```

The code I have tried so far is:

```
import json

file = open(name, 'r') #read in rows of data from text file
file_rows = file.read()

file_rows = file_rows.split('\n')

for x_file in file_rows:

    x_file2 = x_file.split(',')

    my_text_file = open(text_file_path, 'r')
    var_a = my_text_file.read() #read in list of lists from text file

    the_list = json.loads(var_a.replace("'", '"'))

    if any(x_file2[0] == x[2] for x in the_list) == True:

    print xfile2[0], x
```

I'm still a bit out there from what I am after. Can someone tell me how I should amend the list comprehension to achieve the desired output?

Thanks

Comment: Is `1` the `id` for Apple. You need to map object with `1` in the list and `1` in the file together OR, this merging is based on the index i.e 0th index of list with first line of file?

Comment: *"amend the list comprehension"* - What list comprehension? You don't have any.

Comment: (1) Why do you want to use a list comprehension?  Your output is text to a file, one line at a time.  A list comprehension is contraindicated.  (2) Why are there quotation marks around the text file items?  The commas are enough of a separator.  (3) Why do you bludgeon this with the JSON package?  The file format is barely CSV.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri my mapping is if element zero of each row of the text file read in and split matches with any element 2 of the list of list then print element 2 of that list and the list containing the row of the next file in question.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample code for list comprehension with the use of `itertools`:

```
import itertools

with open('/tmp/my_text_file.txt') as f:
    new_list = [list(itertools.chain(item[1][:1], item[0].strip().replace("'", "").split(", "))) for item in zip(f.readlines(), var_a)]

# new_list = [['apple', '1', '20,000', 'USA'], ['banana', '2', '45,000', 'Russia'], ['orange', '3', '56,000', 'China']]
```